# Hibernate multi-level JOIN FETCH resulting in Column Name Not Found in ResultSet exception

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, join, fetch

I have a query attempting to do a full load of an entity:

```
SELECT DISTINCT i, ifi, iti FROM Item i 
LEFT JOIN FETCH i.inboundLinks iil 
LEFT JOIN FETCH iil.fromItem ifi 
LEFT JOIN FETCH i.outboundLinks iol 
LEFT JOIN FETCH iol.toItem iti 
LEFT JOIN FETCH i.itemValues 
LEFT JOIN FETCH ifi.inboundLinks ifiil 
LEFT JOIN FETCH ifiil.fromItem ififi 
LEFT JOIN FETCH ifi.outboundLinks ifiol 
LEFT JOIN FETCH ifiol.toItem ifiti 
LEFT JOIN FETCH ifi.itemValues 
LEFT JOIN FETCH iti.inboundLinks itiil 
LEFT JOIN FETCH itiil.fromItem itifi 
LEFT JOIN FETCH iti.outboundLinks itiol 
LEFT JOIN FETCH itiol.toItem ititi 
LEFT JOIN FETCH iti.itemValues 
WHERE i.itemId = :itemId
```

As you can see it traverses down multiple levels, passing through the same entities in different paths.

When this executes, I get the following error:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column name link_id1_11_1_ was not found in this ResultSet.
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.findColumn(PgResultSet.java:2588) ~[postgresql-9.4.1212.jre7.jar:9.4.1212.jre7]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.getLong(PgResultSet.java:2486) ~[postgresql-9.4.1212.jre7.jar:9.4.1212.jre7]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BigIntTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(BigIntTypeDescriptor.java:63) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:47) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:238) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:234) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:224) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:300) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.extractKeysFromResultSet(Loader.java:789) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:714) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:972) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:930) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:336) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2617) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    ... 92 common frames omitted
```

I can see in the generated sql that the problem is the name of the column being looked up is missing an underscore at the end.  Here is the relevant snippet of the generated sql:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  item0_.item_id               AS item_id1_9_0_,
  item2_.item_id               AS item_id1_9_1_,
  item4_.item_id               AS item_id1_9_2_,
  ...
  inboundlin6_.to_item_id      AS to_item_9_11_1__,
  inboundlin6_.link_id         AS link_id1_11_1__,   ---- problem line
  item7_.transaction_id        AS transact2_9_6_,
```

I have looked at countless questions related to this error message, and nearly all of them suggest using a non-default naming strategy.  I did this by adding this line to application.properties (I am using Spring-Boot with hibernate):

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

This does not seem to change anything.  At any rate, it looks to me like there is just a bug in the hibernate code.

Is anyone aware of a solution to this problem?

Comment: What Hibernate version are you using?